# Where can I find Python code examples, or tutorials, of social networking style functions/components?

Tags: python, social-networking, pylons, get-satisfaction

I am looking for **tutorials** and/or **examples** of certain components of a social network web app that may include Python code examples of:

- user account auto-gen function(database)
- friend/follow function (Twitter/Facebook style)
- messaging/reply function (Twitter style)
- live chat function (Facebook style)
- blog function
- public forums (like Get Satisfaction or Stack Overflow)
- profile page template auto-gen function

I just want to start getting my head around how Python can be used to make these features. I am not looking for a solution like **Pinax** since  it is built upon **Django** and I will be ultimately using **Pylons** or just straight up **Python**.

Comment: my hat's off to you - integrating Plurk, facebook, twitter, and voting all in one!

Comment: i was thinking 'maybe i should not add 'Twitter/Facebook style' to my post' because people like warren would go for a cheap shot. shame on you.

Comment: @J3M 7OR3 - that's no "cheap shot": it's a point that you've asked a very large question, which won't have a real answer.. Nicholas78 (http://stackoverflow.com/users/345480/nicolas78) makes a great point in pointing out that you're asking a question too big to answer

Comment: warren, yeah i realize that it's a big question but Nicholas78 answered it in directly. he guided me to the next step. to me that is an answer enough :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you're not interested in a fixed solution but want to program it yourself, do I get that correctly? If not: Go with a fixed solution. This will be a *lot* of programming effort, and whatever you want to do afterwards, doing it in another framework than you intended will be a *much* smaller problem.

But if you're actually interested in the programming experience, and you haven't found any tutorials googling for, say "messaging python tutorial", then that's because these are large-scale projects,- if you describe a project of this size, you're so many miles above actual lines of code that the concrete programming language almost doesn't matter (or at least you don't get stuck with the details). So you need to break these things down into smaller components.

For example, the friend/follow function: How to insert stuff into a table with a user id, how to keep a table of follow-relations, how to query for a user all texts from people she's following (of course there's also some infrastructural issues if you hit >100.000 people, but you get the idea ;). Then you can ask yourself, which is the part of this which I don't know how to do in Python? If your problem, on the other hand, is breaking down the problems into these subproblems, you need to start looking for help on that, but that's probably not language specific (so you might just want to start googling for "architecture friend feed" or whatever). Also, you could ask that here (beware, each bullet point makes for a huge question in itself ;). Finally, you could get into the Pinax code (don't know it but I assume it's open source) and see how they're doing it. You could try porting some of their stuff to Pylons, for example, so you don't have to reinvent their wheel, learn how they do it, end up in the framework you wanted and maybe even create something reusable by others.

sorry for tl;dr, that's because I don't have a concrete URL to point you to!

Comment: Nicolas78 this seems to be a pretty smart answer. you are right in that i want to learn how to program each of these components on their own. breaking each of these components down into smaller bits seems like the way to go. thanks!